# T 5.3.2 Dynamic Buttons in ajaxform

Tags: tapestry

after updating to Tapestry 5.3.2, my `@ActivationRequestParameter` does not work anymore ..

having a form like this

```
<t:zone t:id="formZone" id="formZone" t:update="show">
    <form t:id="ajaxForm" t:type="form" t:zone="formZone" style="border: 2px solid #eee; padding: 15px">

        <input type="submit" id="sub" type="submit" value="Accept"/><br/><br/>

        <t:errors/>

        ${form}

    </form>
</t:zone>
```

trying to catch the input's id like this

```
@ActivationRequestParameter("t:submit")
private String submitter;

void onSuccess() {
    logger.debug("onSuccess ," +submitter);

    if (request.isXHR()) {
        ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(formZone);
    }
}
```

gives me the error

```
org.apache.tapestry5.runtime.ComponentEventException
Input string '["sub","sub"]' is not valid; the character '[' at position 1 is not valid.

org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException
Input string '["sub","sub"]' is not valid; the character '[' at position 1 is not valid.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Input string '["sub","sub"]' is not valid; the character '[' at position 1 is not valid.
```

Filter stack frames Stack trace

```
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.URLEncoderImpl.decode(URLEncoderImpl.java:144)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ActivationRequestParameterWorker$2.handleEvent(ActivationRequestParameterWorker.java:128)
    org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentInstantiatorSourceImpl$TransformationSupportImpl$1$1.invoke(ComponentInstantiatorSourceImpl.java:443)
```

## Desired Behavoir

actually my goal is to be able to get submit-inputs dynamically in the form via

```
<t:outputraw value="buttonHtml"/>
```

like

```
public Object getButtonHtml(){

    ContentType contentType = new ContentType("text/plain");//responseRenderer.findContentType(this);
    MarkupWriter writer = factory.newPartialMarkupWriter(contentType);


    if(isFavorite){
        writer.element("input").attribute("type", "submit").attribute("class", "sButton")
        .attribute("id", ACTION_REMOVE).attribute("value", messages.get("button_removeFavorite"));
        writer.end();
    } else {
        writer.element("input").attribute("type", "submit").attribute("class", "sButton")
        .attribute("id", ACTION_ADD).attribute("value", messages.get("button_addFavorite"));
        writer.end();
    }


    return writer.toString();
}
```

any hints are warmly welcome :D

Comment: i have no a solution for one button by changing its value, like: `<t:submit t:id="sub" type="submit" value="${label}"/>`, but what if i want to have a dynamic number of button ... ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the

```
@Inject
private Request request;
..request.getParameter("t:submit");
```

did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would possibly would want to create a button using raw output?
At least take a look at the docs and make a [custom component](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-rendering.html).

Take a look at the source of the Checklist component. It buils a list of Renderable Object (the *availableOptions* list) and then renders those in a loop (as seen in the Checklist's template)

Besides, turning your input button into a [tapestry submit button](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Submit.html) should at least resolve the error.

Comment: thanks, for the answer, i want to create the buttons according to the state of the user. i will try the tapestry submit button thoe

Comment: just thought about it again. Even easier than creating a renderable would be if you create an custom object which holds action and context for a single link. Then put those in a list (customized for your user) and do a t:loop which renders a t:submitlink for each of those objects. Then all you need is a onSubmit(Context blah) method, which can decide what to do using the context.

Comment: thx for the inputs ;) - using the loop with 'dynamic' ids made the onSubmit.. or onSuccess.. methods unkown, so error .. couldn't get the submit button to work, as these also needs to be identified, same for linksubmit (what i guess you meant with submitlink